# How can you connect to Yahoo! imap in native android email client?

Tags: email, 8.0-oreo, stock-email-app

I'm running Android 8.0 on an LG V20

When I attempt to connect my Yahoo! mail to the stock android email app I'm unable to enter my application password for Yahoo! Instead the native android email app decides that if "yahoo.com" is in the email address then they would connect me to an OAuth type 2FFA (2 factor authentication) regardless of the fact I chose MANUAL SETUP. When I attempt to connect using the Oath I get a text message from Yahoo! with my 6 digit pin. After entering it there's a small popup at the bottom of the screen that only says 'Not Authenticated' with no indication of why. I've already tried 6 times both using the Yahoo! option and the manual setup option.

POP3 works allows me to connect using my application password that I made in Yahoo!, but it sucks because if I read the email elsewhere, it still appears as unread on my phone.

How can I access my yahoo email with the native android client using IMAP when OAuth isn't working?

EDIT 9-11-2020:
I have the email app source pulled up, and there's an XML that defines providers. Since it's an XML I figured it's probably read at run time and if I could find it and remove the entries for Yahoo then the OAuth plugin shouldn't get triggered.

Here's a link to the email AOSP repository. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r50

This is the app that is getting called. I have android studio and I'd be glad to recompile it if someone has a link to instructions for that.

Comment: [Yahoo uses proprietary protocols](https://flashtool.org/5/download-intel-phone-flash-tool.html) and does not support IMAP idle

Comment: My LG G4 running Anroid 7 is using IMAP protocols to my Yahoo! account, and it works even now. This LG V20 running Android 8.0 tries to connect me to an OAuth app regardless of how I try.

Comment: Behavior of server won't change depending on Android version. Please re-check configuration on the other device (Android 7)//I linked you to Marcel's app and he is rarely wrong

Comment: It's not the behaviour of the server. The problem is that the phone (ie client) tries to plug in some intermediate 2FFA. If the phone didn't do that there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @beeshyam. Who is Marcel?

Comment: Sorry. He is best known for his open source privacy oriented apps like Net guard, Xprivacy, XPrivacyLua etc. He is currently developing /developed FairEmail, another privacy oriented Email client and I trust him fully on his expertise. All his projects are on XDA